# I'm getting extra string char when I use GetBody<System.IO.Stream>() for BrokeredMessage but works perfect with GetBody<string>() c#

Tags: c#, azure, stream, azureservicebus, brokeredmessage

```
    Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver messageReceiver = messagingFactory.CreateMessageReceiver(                    Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SubscriptionClient.FormatSubscriptionPath(
                        "TopicName",
                        "SubscriptionName"),
                    Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ReceiveMode.PeekLock);

 List<BrokeredMessage> brokeredMessages = new List<BrokeredMessage>();
 var messages = messageReceiver.ReceiveBatch(10);
 brokeredMessages.AddRange(messages);

 foreach (var message in messages)              
 var stream = message.GetBody<System.IO.Stream>();
                    var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                    var body = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

which gives wrong output with  -

```
@string3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/�h
{"MyID":"121"}
```

When I use below it works perfect -

```
string body = message.GetBody<string>();
```

output - `{"MyID":"121"}`

why this happens ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that this is how you send your messages:

```cs
MyClass myObj = new MyClass { MyID = "121" };
string json = ... // serialize myObj to JSON
var message = new BrokeredMessage(json);
```

However, this does not send your content as-is. You are actually using this constructor overload:

```cs
public BrokeredMessage(object serializableObject)
```

and it does:

> Initializes a new instance of the BrokeredMessage class from a given
>   object by using DataContractSerializer with a binary
>   XmlDictionaryWriter.

So, your string gets serialized into XML and then formatted with binary formatting. That's what you see in the message content (namespace and some non-readable characters).

`message.GetBody<string>` works fine, because it does the reverse: it deserializes the message from binary XML.

`message.GetBody<Stream>` is a raw operation, thus you get raw bytes.

To serialize the content as-is, you should be using `Stream`-based constructor overload:

```cs
var message = new BrokeredMessage(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)), true);
```

Comment: oh great exaplanation thanks a lot :) which is good to use stream or string ?

Comment: Both are okay, but you have to keep sender and receiver in sync. If you already serialize to JSON, then `Stream` makes more sense to me.

Comment: i'm reading message using  Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver messageReceiver